# Display data from SQL query on email body of Java sent email

Tags: java

I have a query running on SQL I would like the results of this query to print on the email body of the email I send using java.How can I go about it below is the body code its not displaying the query

```
    EmailQuery.sendEmail("me@gmail","Query", "Select * from Employee");
```

Comment: you need to set up a db connection, *run that query* against the and store the results in a variable, then use the contents of that variable in your EmailQuery.sendEmail() call.

Comment: I have created String em = null;
if(rs.next())
    em = rs.getString(("name"));                                                                                                  When I add it to EmailQuery.sendEmail() Is comes as a text because EmailQuery.sendEmail is public static void query (String Email, String subject, String em )